# Error al parsear con JSON

Tags: javascript, laravel

resulta que tengo un botón que llama a una función con jQuery y abre un modal en el cual se ve una vista más detallada del producto, pero cuando el nombre del producto tiene comillas dobles o algún otro símbolo, el modal no se muestra y me muestra el siguiente error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 55.

He leído que puedo poner un \ antes de las comillas dobles para evitar el problema pero no me parece lo más óptimo, espero haber sido claro, muchas gracias de antemano.

Este es el código de la card:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="col-auto col-sm-6 mx-0 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 text-dark my-2">
        <div class="card shadow h-100 w-100">
            <a aria-label="Abrir más información" class="btn-open-modal" role="button" onclick="showModalProduct('{{$product}}')">
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            </a>
            <!-- src=/images/productos/{{$product->image}} -->
            <img class="card-img-top border-0" loading="lazy" height="275" width="230" src="/images/productos/{{$product->image}}" alt="{{'Imagen de '.$product->name}}" title="{{'Imagen de '.$product->name}}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-tittle font-weight-bold text-uppercase">{{Str::limit($product->name, $limit="22", $end="...")}}</div>
                <div class="card-text text-left font-weight-bold price">${{$product->price}}</div>
                <div class="modified"><b>Modificado:</b>
                    <p class="font-italic">{{Str::limit($product->updated_at, $limit="10", $end="")}}</p>
                </div>
                @if ($product->stock > 0)
                <a href="{{route('carro.agregar', $product->slug)}}" class="btn btn-primary w-100 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Agregar al carro</a>
                @else
                <a class="btn btn-primary disabled text-white w-100 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Sin stock</a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

esta es la función de jQuery:

```
function showModalProduct(product_destacated) {

        var product_modal = JSON.parse(product_destacated);
        //edito los datos del modal con los de JSON
        $("#modal-product .product-title").text(product_modal.name);
        $("#modal-product .product-description").text(product_modal.description);
        $("#modal-product .product-price").text("$ " + product_modal.price);
        $("#modal-product .product-stock").text(product_modal.stock);
        if (product_modal.stock > 0) {
            $("#modal-product .product-stock").text(product_modal.stock);
            $("#link").attr('href', "agregar-al-carro/" + product_modal.slug);
        } else {
            $("#modal-product .product-stock").text("Sin stock");
            $("#link").attr('href', null);
            $("#link").addClass("disabled");
        }
        //inicializamos variables vacías para las imagenes
        var img1 = "";
        var img2 = "";
        var img3 = "";
        //antes  "/images/productos/" + 
        var img_p = product_modal.image;
        //si el tamaño del array es = 0 borramos todo el contenido de preview-thumbnail y preview-pic y luego lo agregamos con append 
        if (product_modal.images.length == 0) {
            $("#modal-product .preview-pic").empty();
            $("#modal-product .preview-thumbnail").empty();
            $("#modal-product .preview-pic").append(
                "<div class='active tab-pane  my-1' id='pic-principal'><img id='img-p' height='280' width='160' src='/images/productos/" + img_p + "'/></div>");
            $("#modal-product .preview-thumbnail").append(
                "<li class='active my-1'><a data-target='#pic-principal' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' width='60' src='/images/productos/" + img_p + "' id='img-p'/></a></li>");
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < product_modal.images.length; i++) {
                $("#modal-product .preview-pic").empty();
                $("#modal-product .preview-thumbnail").empty();
                //antes = "images/productos/adicionales/"+
                img1 = product_modal.images[i].image1;
                img2 = product_modal.images[i].image2;
                img3 = product_modal.images[i].image3;
                if (product_modal.images[i].image1 != null && product_modal.images[i].image2 != null && product_modal.images[i].image3 != null) {
                    $("#modal-product .preview-pic").append(
                        "<div class='tab-pane active my-1' id='pic-principal'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-p' src='" + img_p + "'/></div>" +
                        "<div class='tab-pane my-1' id='pic-1'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-1' src='" + img1 + "'/></div>" +
                        "<div class='tab-pane my-1' id='pic-2'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-2' src='" + img2 + "'/></div>" +
                        "<div class='tab-pane my-1' id='pic-3'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-3' src='" + img3 + "'/></div>"
                    );
                    $("#modal-product .preview-thumbnail").append(
                        "<li class='active my-1'><a data-target='#pic-principal' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img_p + "' id='img-p'/></a></li>" +
                        "<li class='my-1'><a data-target='#pic-1' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img1 + "' id='img-1'/></a></li>" +
                        "<li class='my-1'><a data-target='#pic-2' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img2 + "' id='img-2'/></a></li>" +
                        "<li class='my-1'><a data-target='#pic-3' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img3 + "' id='img-3'/></a></li>"
                    );
                } else if (product_modal.images[i].image1 != null && product_modal.images[i].image2 != null) {
                    $("#modal-product .preview-pic").append(
                        "<div class='tab-pane active my-1' id='pic-principal'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-p' src='" + img_p + "'/></div>" +
                        "<div class='tab-pane my-1' id='pic-1'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-1' src='" + img1 + "'/></div>" +
                        "<div class='tab-pane my-1' id='pic-2'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-2' src='" + img2 + "'/></div>"
                    );
                    $("#modal-product .preview-thumbnail").append(
                        "<li class='active my-1'><a data-target='#pic-principal' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img_p + "' id='img-p'/></a></li>" +
                        "<li class='my-1'><a data-target='#pic-1' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img1 + "' id='img-1'/></a></li>" +
                        "<li class='my-1'><a data-target='#pic-2' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img2 + "' id='img-2'/></a></li>"
                    );
                } else {
                    $("#modal-product .preview-pic").append(
                        "<div class='tab-pane active my-1' id='pic-principal'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-p' src='" + img_p + "'/></div>" +
                        "<div class='tab-pane my-1' id='pic-1'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' id='img-1' src='" + img1 + "'/></div>"
                    );
                    $("#modal-product .preview-thumbnail").append(
                        "<li class='active my-1'><a data-target='#pic-principal' data-toggle='tab'><img alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' height='280' width='160' src='" + img_p + "' id='img-p'/></a></li>" +
                        "<li class='my-1'><a data-target='#pic-1' data-toggle='tab'><img height='60' alt='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' title='Imagen de " + product_modal.name + "' width='81' src='" + img1 + "' id='img-1'/></a></li>"
                    );
                }
    
            }
        }
        $("#modal-product").modal('show');
    }
```

Comment: Intenta con `onclick="showModalProduct('{!! $product !!}')"`

Comment: @JuanRivera me da este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token al poner onclick="showModalProduct('{{!! $product !!}}')"

Comment: Solo una llave no 2

Comment: Mismo error con onclick="showModalProduct('{!! $product !!}')"